# Need some help in creating a procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I need some help here.

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `point` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `lefth` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `righth` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `referel` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateadded` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1, 1000, 2, 4, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (2, 0, 3, 5, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (3, 0, 6, 9, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (4, 0, 14, 7, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (5, 0, 8, 0, 2, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (6, 0, 0, 0, 3, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (7, 0, 15, 19, 4, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (8, 0, 10, 11, 5, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (9, 0, 0, 0, 3, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (10, 0, 0, 0, 8, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (11, 0, 12, 13, 8, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (12, 0, 0, 0, 11, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (13, 0, 0, 0, 11, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (14, 0, 16, 17, 4, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (15, 0, 0, 0, 7, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (16, 0, 0, 0, 4, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (17, 0, 0, 18, 14, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (18, 0, 0, 0, 17, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (19, 0, 20, 0, 7, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (20, 0, 0, 0, 19, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

I want to write a procedure when provide with a value as parameter will return all the values form the table which is coming under the passed parameter.

something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
-- 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `emp_heir`(
        IN param1 INTEGER(11)
    )
BEGIN
select lefth from users where id = param1;
END$$
```

this will return only the value in the column lefth, but if the value in lefth is having child values (values in lefth and righth of that id) it should return that also. like wise it should continue till the end of the table.

How this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `emp_heir` (IN param1 INTEGER(11), INOUT lResult VARCHAR(255), INOUT rResult VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE lh INT(11);
    DECLARE rh INT(11);

    IF lResult IS NULL THEN
        SET lResult := '';
    END IF;
    IF rResult IS NULL THEN
        SET rResult := '';
    END IF;

    SELECT lefth, righth FROM users where id = param1 INTO lh, rh;

    IF lh != 0 THEN
        SET lResult := CONCAT(lResult, lh, ',');
    END IF;
    IF rh != 0 THEN
        SET rResult := CONCAT(rResult, rh, ',');
    END IF;

    IF lh != 0 THEN
        CALL emp_heir(lh, lResult, rResult);
    END IF;
    IF rh != 0 THEN
        CALL emp_heir(rh, lResult, rResult);
    END IF;
END$$
```

Check this. To test:

```
call emp_heir(2, @lresult, @rresult, 0);
select @lresult, @rresult;
```

Just interesting, why don't you do this in application? =)

**UPD**

If you get error on this, execute

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;
```

If error will appear again, try to increase the value

Comment: Hmm.. I've executed this on data from your question and i got +--------------+------------+
| @lresult     | @rresult   |
+--------------+------------+
| 3,6,8,10,12, | 5,9,11,13, |
+--------------+------------+

Comment: yeah i got it now. previously i was using sql manager 2010. got the result when i ran it from phpmyadmin.this is not the result i was looking for. if i give 2 as initial value the lresult shud contain 3,6,9 and rresult should contain 5,8,10,11,12,13. am trying it out myself, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

it this is what you want ?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my(
    IN number INT,   
    OUT lefte INT,
    OUT righte INT

)
BEGIN
   SELECT lefth, righth 
   FROM users WHERE id = number INTO lefte , righte;

END;

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the call is like :

```
CALL my(4,@lefth,@righth);
SELECT @lefth,@righth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `emp_heir` (IN param1 INTEGER(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE lh INT(11);
    DECLARE rh INT(11);
    DECLARE lresult VARCHAR(255) default '';
    DECLARE rresult VARCHAR(255) default '';
    SET lh := param1;
    SET rh := param1;
    REPEAT
        SELECT lefth FROM users WHERE id = lh INTO lh;
        SET lresult := CONCAT(lresult, lh, ',');
    UNTIL lh = 0 END REPEAT;
    REPEAT
        SELECT righth FROM users WHERE id = rh INTO rh;
        SET rresult := CONCAT(rresult, rh, ',');
    UNTIL rh = 0 END REPEAT;
    SELECT LEFT(lresult, LENGTH(lresult) - 3) AS lefths, LEFT(rresult, LENGTH(rresult) - 3) AS righths;
END$$
```

Did you meen something like that? This procedure recursively gets all `lefth` and `righth` values and puts it into separate strings.

Comment: Thanks.This almost worked. But once the righth or lefth of the passed parameter is fetched, then it has to fetch righth and lefth of the child values

Comment: I changed the query to this'BEGIN
    DECLARE lh INT(11);
    DECLARE rh INT(11);
    DECLARE lresult VARCHAR(255) default '';
    DECLARE rresult VARCHAR(255) default '';
    SET lh := param1;
    SET rh := param1;
    REPEAT
        SELECT lefth,righth FROM users WHERE id = lh or id = rh INTO lh,rh;
        SET lresult := CONCAT(lresult, lh, ',' ,rh, ',');
    UNTIL lh = 0 and rh = 0 END REPEAT;
    
    SELECT LEFT(lresult, LENGTH(lresult) - 3) AS lefths;
END' but this gives error 'result consisited of more than one row'

Comment: That's right, `SELECT ... INTO ...` can't work with more than one row.